# How can this simple dice roller be optimized or cleaned up?

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, dice

Well I finally did it, I set my expectations lower, and I was able to create a simple application that rolls 2 dice. My question is, how can this be optimized, or cleaned up? The code seems longer than it needs to be, but maybe it can be cleaned up. I also enjoy how seeing how others may code the same thing. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you

```js
    function rollDice() {
      var d1Results = [];
      var d2Results = [];
      var diceSum = [];
      var twoTotal = [];
      var threeTotal = [];
      var fourTotal = [];
      var fiveTotal = [];
      var sixTotal = [];
      var sevenTotal = [];
      var eightTotal = [];
      var nineTotal = [];
      var tenTotal = [];
      var elevenTotal = [];
      var twelveTotal = [];
      var sum = 0;

      for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        dice1 = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        d1Results.push(dice1);
        dice2 = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        d2Results.push(dice2);

        sum = dice1 + dice2;
        diceSum.push(sum);

        if (sum == 2) {
          twoTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 3) {
          threeTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 4) {
          fourTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 5) {
          fiveTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 6) {
          sixTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 7) {
          sevenTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 8) {
          eightTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 9) {
          nineTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 10) {
          tenTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 11) {
          elevenTotal.push(sum);
        }
        if (sum == 12) {
          twelveTotal.push(sum);
        }
      }
      console.log(d1Results);
      console.log(d2Results);
      console.log(diceSum);
      console.log(`
      2: ${twoTotal.length}
      3: ${threeTotal.length}
      4: ${fourTotal.length}
      5: ${fiveTotal.length}
      6: ${sixTotal.length}
      7: ${sevenTotal.length}
      8: ${eightTotal.length}
      9: ${nineTotal.length}
      10: ${tenTotal.length}
      11: ${elevenTotal.length}
      12: ${twelveTotal.length}
      `);
    }

    rollDice();
```

Answer (score 0):

I begin with adding a block to make a new scope.

Then I make single purpose functions `rollDie` (roll a single die), `rollDice` (curried function where I can choose the number of faces on a die, how many dice should be rolled and how many times to repeat) and `sumDice`

```js
console.clear();
{
  "use strict";
  const results = [];
  
  const rollDie = faces => Math.ceil(Math.random() * faces)
  
  const rollDice = faces => many => times => {
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++ ) {
      const temp = []      
      for (let j = 0; j < many; j++) {
        temp.push(rollDie(faces))
      }
      results.push(temp)
    }
    return results;
  }
  
  const sumDice = result => {
    return result.reduce((carry1, item1) => {
      const index = item1.reduce((carry2, item2) => carry2 + item2, 0);
      carry1[index] = (carry1[index] || 0) + 1;
      return carry1;
    }, {})
  }
  
  let result = rollDice(6)(2)(1000);
  let sum = sumDice(result);
  
  console.log({result}, {sum});
  
}
```